# Move files older than 90 days in a set of directories where the directory name contains certain text using batch or powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have a server where there are hundreds of sub directories, that may possibly contain files with a .flv extension that are older than 90 days.  I need to find these files, but only in the folders that have the word "ProdStream" in their name.

The purpose of this is to archive the files to AWS (I have a working script for this) with the original path of the file preserved in a log.

I can find the files in all the sub folders using forfiles:

```
forfiles /P "SRC_PATH" /S /M *.flv /D -90 /C "cmd /C move @file "DEST_PATH""
```

However, forfiles doesn't allow me to use the folder name as a variable.  At least not in what I've tried.  So I tried using the for command.

```
set stream=SRC_PATH
FOR /D /R %stream% %%X IN (ProdStream*) DO [something]
```

This works, but only partially as I can't find the right command to put after the DO to find the files.

I also need to save the list of files with complete path information.  I have been using this:

```
forfiles /P "SRC_PATH" /S /M *.flv /D -90 /C "cmd /C echo @path @fsize" >MY_LOG_FILE
```

Which works, but doesn't filter for the ProdStream text in the folder name.

I am open to doing this in PowerShell as well as batch.

My PowerShell is weak, but it can get stronger!

Ideas?

Server is Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if work for you:

```
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad/b/s c:\yourfolder\*Prodstream*') do (
forfiles /P "%%~fa" /M *.flv /D -90 /C "cmd /C move @file "DEST_PATH""
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope not to turn you off powershell but since your willing to consider this as an option I present the following

```
$Path = "C:\temp"
$FolderFilter = "ProdStream"
$copyPath = "C:\archive"
$log = "c:\log"

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse | Where-Object { ! $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Extension -eq ".flv" -and $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).Adddays(-90) -and ($_.FullName -split "\\")[-2] -match $FolderFilter } | ForEach-Object{
    Add-Content -Path $log "The following was archived $($_.FullName)"
    #Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $copyPath 
}
```

Ok, I will try to break this down as best I can.

1. Use Get-ChildItem. Its like `dir` from cmd. In the starting path designated by the variable $path search for all files and directories. I know that is not what you want but keep reading
2. The Where-Object clause is where the magic happens of you criteria for matching files. I will break down the conditions

   - ! `$_.PSIsContainer`. I am going to assume you have a older version of powershell. This will return all files and not directories.
   - `$_.Extension -eq ".flv"`. You wanted files of an `.flv` persuasion.
   - `$_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)`. This will check and see if the created time of the file is older than 90 days from now.
   - `($_.FullName -split "\\")[-2]`. This condition will take the file path and convert it into an array of folders and files. Take that array and return the second last item which would be the folder name of the file in question. Example would be `C:\temp\ProdStreamStuf\IMG_0571.JPG` would return `ProdStreamStuf`. Take the parent folder name and see if it contains `$FolderFilter` which in our case is `ProdStream`. `-match` would return `true` if and part of the name contain `ProdStream`. Also `-match` is case-insensitive by default.
3. If **all** of the above conditions are met then take each file and process them via ForEach-Object. *Note* this could be piped straight into other Powershell cmdlets but im trying to keep this basic.
4. You mentioned you wanted to store the located files in a log so output the full path of the file to a log with `Add-Content`
5. After *all* of that copy the file to its new home which is designated by `$copyPath`
6. Save this into a file with a `.ps1` extension and you can double click on it.
7. *For testing* I put a comment `#` on this line `Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $copyPath` which will prevent it from running and you can just read the `$log` to see if it will move the files you want it to. Then if it is working remove the `#`

**Note**
If you dont normally run PowerShell scripts you will get an error in regard to the `ExecutionPolicy`. If that is the case you can open up a PowerShell session and run this `Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned` which will allow local unsigned scripts (like the one you just made )on the computer while ensuring scripts from the internet need to be signed. Also you would need to change all the `$` variables to match your needed paths. Also, depending on how many files and folder you have you could rearrange the conditions. Conditions in PowerShell are evaluated left to right. If one is false it will not evaluate the rest. So you could put `($_.FullName -split "\\")[-2] -match $FolderFilter` first so that if the parent folder does not contain ProdStream dont bother looking at anything else.